# How to get process instance from UWP process group?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create some kind of a Task Manager Program in C#/.NET Console Application. My program have to be able to start process by name, kill process by id and etc. And currently I faced with such a problem, for example, 
when I perform code like `Process calcProc=Process.Start("calc.exe")`.
Than I wrap this process to work with it further in my program.
At this point, everything works fine. 
But when i'm trying to kill that process by id, something like that `Process proc= Process.GetProcessByID(calcProc.Id)` and `proc.Kill()` my program fails with `System.ArgumentException: 'Process with an Id of calcProc.Id is not running.'`

I made some research and it turned out, that some processes like `calc.exe`, when running are united in UWP process groups to improve system performance. Such process group has another id and system name for that specific process.

Is there some way to get concrete instance of some process from such UWP process group, in order to perform operations, which are described above?